# I'm struggling to install darkstat on an Amazon EC2 server running Amazon Linux. Any tips?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, yum

Hello and thanks in advance for reading through this question. Disclaimer: I'm still quite a newbie when it comes to managing a server. I'm running an Amazon EC2 server (which is running Amazon Linux) and I'm attempting to install darkstat (a traffic monitor - https://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat) via SSH but am experiencing difficulties.

Unfortunately, `sudo yum install darkstat` doesn't work (apparently darkstat isn't part of Amazon's repository). I attempted to manually install darkstat by taking the following steps (which are recommended on the darkstat website):

- First, I installed the prerequisites:

  ```
  sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
  sudo yum install libpcap-devel
  ```
- Then I began the process of installing darkstat:

  ```
  cd /usr/src (which could be the wrong location for all I know)
  wget https://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/darkstat-3.0.719.tar.bz2
  tar xjvf darkstat-3.0.719.tar.bz2
  cd darkstat-3.0.719
  ./configure
  make
  ```

According to the darkset guide, I should be able to type "darkstat -i eth0" (without quotes of course) at this point and the magic should begin. Unfortunately I receiving a dreaded "bash: darkstat: command not found" message instead, which suggests that darkstat failed to install.

Any idea where I'm going wrong during the attempted installation? I didn't notice any glaring errors during the install process - here's the install log in case it proves to be helpful. Thanks again for taking a look at this question and I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions that you might have:

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx darkstat-3.0.719]# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking if we want debug code... sure
checking if your C compiler wants a hit off the pipe... sure does
checking if your C compiler has a link-time optimizer... sure does
checking for deflate in -lz... yes
checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
checking for library containing socket... none required
checking for library containing hstrerror... none required
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/filio.h usability... no
checking sys/filio.h presence... no
checking for sys/filio.h... no
checking for library containing getifaddrs... none required
checking ifaddrs.h usability... yes
checking ifaddrs.h presence... yes
checking for ifaddrs.h... yes
checking sys/sockio.h usability... no
checking sys/sockio.h presence... no
checking for sys/sockio.h... no
checking for pcap_loop in -lpcap... yes
checking pcap.h usability... yes
checking pcap.h presence... yes
checking for pcap.h... yes
checking for library containing setproctitle... no
checking for library containing strlcpy... no
checking for library containing strlcat... no
checking bsd/string.h usability... no
checking bsd/string.h presence... no
checking for bsd/string.h... no
checking bsd/unistd.h usability... no
checking bsd/unistd.h presence... no
checking for bsd/unistd.h... no
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating darkstat.8
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx darkstat-3.0.719]#
```

Comment: You haven't shown us anything useful to help you.

Comment: I don't use AWS, but as far as I know Amazon Linux is based on RHEL/CentOS (not sure if it's 6 or 7 though). Anyway, if it's CentOS6 based, you could use [Repoforge](http://repoforge.org/use/)  and it it's based on 7, you can use the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repo and install it with`yum`.

Comment: That's only the output of `./configure`.  You haven't run `make` or `make install`.